# Constructing models of recursively axiomatizable theories

Tags: logic, model-theory, computability

I am trying to prove the following statement:
Given a consistent recursively axiomatizable theory (in a language that only contains one binary relation symbol $R$) then $T$ has a model of the form $(\omega,R)$, where R is $\Delta_{2}$.

To be honest I don't even know how to start to approach this problem, so any hint would be appreciated. I would like also to have any reference to study how to construct this kind of models, or in general, is there any book to understand properly recursively axiomatizable theories? What is known for them? Which kind of models do they have?

Comment: Have you tried just building a model by the Henkin construction and seeing what you get?

Comment: The high-level viewpoint is that the set of completions of a consistent recursively axiomatizable theory can be represented as the set of paths through a computable subtree of $2^{< \omega}$, and at least one of those paths is computable from $0'$, that is, at least one of the paths is $\Delta^0_2$.   This is all standard material in mathematical logic, so to help others write better answers it would help for the question to include more context - what have you seen, and what kind of course are you taking?